# ¿Cómo crear View desde la Activity con estos valores?

Tags: java, android

Este es mi `View` en el `layout`:

```
<View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
  android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
  android:alpha="0.1"
  android:background="#FF0000FF" />
```

pero necesito crearlo igual desde una `Activity`, lo que he conseguido de momento es esto:

```
view0 = new View(MainActivity.this);
view0.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
lm.addView(view0);
```

Lo que hago es crear botones cargando los datos de una lista, pues quiero crear un `View` debajo de cada botón con esas características pero no sé como puedo hacerlo

```
   public void crearCategoria() {

        // carga la lista
        final List lista = mDatabase.ReadCategorias();

        // borra linearlayout
        ll_menu_categorias1.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            //crea los botones con los datos de la lista
            btn0 = new Button(MainActivity.this);
            // parametros del botón
            btn0.setText(lista.get(i).toString());
            btn0.setTextSize(14);
            btn0.setPadding(26,0,0,0);
            btn0.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            btn0.setTextAppearance(ContextApp.getAppContext(), R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless_Colored);
            btn0.setAllCaps(false);
            btn0.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
            btn0.setCompoundDrawablePadding(35);
            int imgResource = R.drawable.categoria_nueva;
            btn0.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(imgResource, 0, 0, 0);
            btn0.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            btn0.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
            // los añade al linearlayout
            ll_menu_categorias1.addView(btn0);


        //view
        view0 = new View(MainActivity.this);
        view0.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        ll_menu_categorias1.addView(view0);
        //
```

Ese es mi código pero solamente crea los botones, los `View` no

Comment: Por lo que veo, que igual me equivoco, creas los view como separadores, porque no meter un Space???

Answer (score 1):

En un principio tendrías que definir parámetros para la vista y aplicarlos. No lo he probado con `View`, te lo paso por si funciona y puedes usarlo, en teoría no tiene por que no funcionar:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
param.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
view.setLayoutParams(param);
```

**Añadido para contestar a la pregunta editada:**
Parece que para añadir una vista necesitas hacer el `addView` con parámetros, igual que para hacer un `update`. Puede que esto sea lo que falte para que funcione:

```
addView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params);
```

Te dejo el enlace [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewManager.html)

**Añadido 2:** para dar dimensiones al `view` esto debería funcionar

```
LayoutParams params=view0.getLayoutParams();
params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
params.height = height;
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);    
view0.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: He editado la pregunta para explicar exactamente lo que necesito @Carmen

Comment: No se crea o por lo menos no es visible, creo que el problema es que necesito que se cree con `android:layout_width="match_parent"` y `android:layout_height="1dp"` pero no sé como hacerlo desde Java

Comment: He editado de nuevo con cómo añadir ancho y alto, a ver si así funciona ;)

Comment: He probado lo que comentas pero recibo este error al cerrarse la aplicación `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference`

Comment: ¿si le pones el width con un número si te funciona? Porque si es el caso parece que el problema es el valor del "match parent", sino el problema es el modo de setear el view.

Comment: Mismo error si pongo un número en **witdh**

Comment: Pues entonces ya lo siento pero no se me ocurre como ponerlo.